# I am unable to start TNSListener service for Oracle10G

Tags: oracle10g, listener, tns

I am unable to restart/start/stop TNSListener service. I am getting following error:-
"The OracleDb_10gTNSListener Service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they have no work to do, for example, the performance logs and Alerts Service". Please help me

Comment: has this worked before before now?

Comment: yes it was working before fine

Comment: Actually I don't have the solution to this problem but most time I just try to restart it several times. Is the OracleService started?

Comment: yup after i restarted my pc ...service resumed

Comment: cool. that fix it for me most times

Comment: also this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28141225/631527

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Check your ip address and copy it.

Step 2: Open (**listener.ora**) in notepad and replace the HOST ip address with your current ip address.That you copied earlier.

**Note:** Do not forget to replace the second entry of HOST ip.

Step 3: Now open (**tnsnames.ora**) with notepad and replace HOST ip address with your current ip address.

Finally start your listner service from windows services or from command prompt.
Hope this will work.
Worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. i was starting the service second time after installation of DB server in my local setup. My Ip address was assigned dynamically by wifi router, and hence the ip address entry which worked first time did not work the next time i connected to the network. I changed the host as localhost instead of ipv4 address in both the .ora files and it worked! I also added hosts file entry for localhost. In windows 7 this path is in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc.

Comment: it did the trick for me few times but not anymore. what else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this issue by replacing the `HOST` values in the following two .ora files with "localhost". Change [username] to your username. The files may be in a different location on your computer.

Note that there is one change in listener.ora and two changes in tnsnames.ora.

After making the change, I rebooted my computer. I haven't had any problem since.

**C:\app[username]\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora** 
    DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\[username]\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\[username]\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

**C:\app[username]\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Open listener.ora file located at C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\

& then check computer name is same as in HOST attribute

Regards
Irshad N

Answer (score 1):

Came exaclty into the same issue today.

As stated here
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3570067?start=0&tstart=0
, in which the problem reported is about Oracle 12c,
I tried deleting listener.ora located into
C:\app\*username*\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin

My issue was on local Oracle express 18. I guess this could be a possible solution for many versions.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be because of other processes, that are trying to connect through that port. In my case it was because of Apache Tomcat. I changed its starting option to manual in the services and stopped it. And tried starting OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener. It was working this time. You can also restart the PC once and check.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying solutions provided by others, first check in your environment settings, if you have correct `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` variable values. Also check in PATH variable, it should be added as `ORACLE_HOME/bin`.
I have two Oracle versions installed on my machine and I had wrong variable values set in my environment due to which it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the wrong IP was set in hosts:
`c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.
The hostname was pointing to a different IP.
After I changed it to the correct IP the listener worked.

Answer (score 0):

Some times this happens when there are two or more listeners are running at the same time. Disable one running listener and try to restart other one.