# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect des

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Please kindly help me as I just installed Oracle 11g but cannot connnect using SQL Devloper using the settings below:

Username: system

Password: mypassword

Hostname: localhost

Port: 1521

SID: XE

**Error message:**

Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

**I checked on Windows Services:**

OracleServiceXE: Started

OracleXETNSListener: Started

I also unable to connect to admin page: `**http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4950**`

It says "This page can't be displayed"

**I also tested to connect using SqlPlus:**

**Test 1: Result is ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred**

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>**sqlplus.exe system/mypassword@XE**

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Apr 22 11:22:31 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Enter user-name:

**Test 2: Result is Successful**

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>**sqlplus.exe system/mypassword**

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Apr 22 11:33:22 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL>

**Test 3: Result is Successful**

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin>**sqlplus.exe / as sysdba**

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Apr 22 11:34:29 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

SQL>

**Listener.log**

```
22-APR-2014 11:53:51 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=SQL Developer)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=admin))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=50010)) * establish * XE * 12505
TNS-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

**tnsnames.ora:**

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = NASAYAO2)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

**LSNRCTL> status**

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                22-APR-2014 14:29:22
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 56 min. 43 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\NASAYAO2\listener\
alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=NASAYAO2)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Please kindly help me.

Comment: For 'test 1', how is XE defined in your `tnsnames.ora`? If it's timing out then it sounds like it's pointing to a different IP address. For SQL Developer, has the DB registered with the listener? What does `lsnrctl status` show? By default it's usually expecting to register with a istener on the server's external IP address, not localhost.

Comment: Hi Alex Poole, I added what you advised me in my question. Please see my update above. Thanks.

Comment: Is this all on one machine (PC), or are the client and server on different machines? It all seems to be one; but what IP address does the host name `NASAYA02` resolve to? It *seems* to resolve to 127.0.0.1 but that's a bit odd, and the behaviour is strange. Basically seems like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22769396/266304) but with extra IP confusion. And if that resolves to a different IP, do you have a firewall running? Do you want people to be able to connect from other clients elsewhere?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole. Thanks for your reply. Yes this is the same machine. NASAYAO2 is actually my localhost computer so it resolve to 127.0.0.1. My intention is to only setup a development database in my local computer. Thank you.

Comment: Then it's going to be less confusing if you set everything up - the `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` in particular - to use `localhost` rather than your machine name, and you might need to force your DB to register against that via the `local_listener` parameter. But the timeout and the APEX issue still sound like another IP is being used sometimes. Maybe DNS resolves it to something else, different to what's in your `hosts` file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open ***Net Manager***. In ***Oracle Net Configuration***, open ***Local***, and then, open ***Listeners***.
2. Select your Listener.
3. In the upper right ComboBox, select ***Database Services***.
4. Clic ***Add Database***.
5. Fill the 3 fields: ***Global Database Name*** (i.e. ORCL.NET. In SQL Plus type SELECT * FROM GLOBAL_NAME), ***Oracle Home Directory*** (i.e. C:\app\User\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1) and ***SID*** (i.e. orcl)
6. File > Save Network Configuration.
7. Restart the ***OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener*** service.

Comment: why did this happen after a random restart? suddenly listener wouldn't start.

Answer (score 9):

I have same problem, but I run on oracle linux.
After searching and testing, i can connect sqldeveloper to my oracle11g without setting my listener.ora or else

here is the syntax that i run on terminal sql

```
alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER='(DESCRIPTION_LIST =  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))))';
```

then

```
alter system register;
```

i get the tutorial
[here](https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/exploring-the-local_listener-parameter/)

Comment: thanks for the solution. It really saved my days I was about to waste :)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Developer maybe you need to add these parameters

```
AddVMOption -Duser.language=en

AddVMOption -Duser.region=US
```

in the file

```
$SQLDEVELOPER_HOME\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I abruptly shutdown the system while being connected to database. Restarting the system does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the database name is XE ?

Do you know what name did you give to database/instance while installing 11g ?

Usually the default name is ORCL.

Try changing Sid name to ORCL and test it.

Answer (score -1):

If you Still getting this
 Error message:

Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Do following steps:
1. open cmd prompt.
2. c:/ services.msc
3. its navigate to system services console there it self once you check it the OracleServiceXE status.
4.then starts the service status(rightclick>start) wait till status showing the running.

Answer (score -2):

if u r using oracle 11g enterprise edition, then do one thing,
u just uninstall it, and again reinstall oracle 11g.
do all the steps carefully.
when installation will finish, 
then go to start menu-oracle 11g-configuration & migration tool-database configuration assistance.
open this & again do configuration
here u will give a sid name .
that sid will be used when u will create a connection in sql developer insteade of xe. 
execept this above dont change other.
i hope it will be definitely work.