# How do I solve error 12505 in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

I'm a programming student and I just began learning databases and SQL. When I try to connect to the databse in SQL Developer it says

> ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.

I tried to install it on my PC tower at home and everything works fine it just doesn't work with my laptop. Even the teacher said he couldn't help me because he doesn't know what to do so I try here because I really don't know what to do.

I tried uninstalling et reinstalling the database multiple times and I made sure every Oracle services were running. My SID is set to XE. My connection is set to basic. The host is 'localhost', the port is '1521' and the SID is 'xe'

Heres is the tnsnames.ora file

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-62JIG0N)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

Heres is the ouput of lsnrctl status in the cmd

```
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                03-F╔VR.-2020 12:04:38
Uptime                    0 days 4 hr. 53 min. 38 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-62JIG0N\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=DESKTOP-62JIG0N)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

Here's the listener.ora file

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-62JIG0N)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please, tell us what you've tried before and take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209962/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-des

Comment: and your database connection has the SID set to XE?

Comment: You've shown the `tnsnames.ora` file, which describes a service-oriented connection for `XE`. From your `lsnrctl status` output, you have no service named XE in your `listener.ora` file. You should show your `listener.ora` file. Also put your comment information (from the answer below) into your post.

Answer (score 0):

What is the 'connection' type of your SQL Dev connection properties? (basic? TNS?)  There is a discconect between the error message ("NS:listener does not currently know of *SID*") while your tnsnames says to connect by service name rather than by SID.  This would indicate that your SQL Dev connection type is 'basic' . . . which doesn't use tnsnames.ora at all.  Since you are using a 'basic' connection, you need to show us the values used.  Also, since it is the listener complaining that he doesn't know of the sid you are requesting, you need to show us the output of the command 'lsnrctl status', so that we can see what the listener *does* know about.

This really a pretty basic problem, so the fact that your instructor doesn't know how to solve it leaves me with a lot of questions about his qualifications to be teaching *anything* involving oracle.

Comment: My connection is set to basic. The host is 'localhost', the port is '1521' and the SID is 'xe'... I've edited the question with the output of lsnrctl because the output is too long and since I'm a beginner student I don't know how to interpret the output

Comment: Ok, since your connection type is 'basic', your tnsnames.ora is not used for this connection.  As for the output of lsnrctl, notice that there is NO entry for your database 'XE'.  This indicates that your database is not started.

Comment: Oh right! And how can I manually start the database? I try clicking on "start database" in the programs but the cmd shows up and I don't know what command to execute. I've seen that I could go into the net manager in "Programs > Oracle - HOME_NAME" but I don't have this in my programs list

Comment: open 'services.msc' (the windows 'services' control panel).  Locate service 'OracleServiceXE' and make sure it is started.  Also make sure it is set for auto start.

Comment: The 'OracleServiceXE' is already running and set to auto. I tried restarting it serveral times as well as stopping and starting it again. That's weird

Comment: open a command prompt.  enter these commands:  'set ORACLE_SID=XE', then 'sqlplus / as sysdba'.  Then, at SQL prompt, 'select instance_name, status from v$instance;'  (quotes are not part of the commands .. I include them to delineate the command as you read it).

Comment: At the last command at the SQL prompt is says 'ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0'

Comment: OK, repeat through 'sqlplus / as sysdba'. Then at the SQL prompt, enter 'startup'.

Comment: Now it says 'ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kspifisp:ksfdread_resilver], [0x000A9F388], [0x000A9F000], [512], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []'

Comment: You've messed up your installation of the rdbms and creation of the database.  We are now way out of scope for this particular thread.  I'd suggest you open a new thread and provide the following: 1) A statement of what you just reported here (when I try to start the database I get this error ....) 2) the OS on which you installed this db, 3) the version and edition of the rdbms (best if you also include the name of the distribution file you used), 4) An extract of the alertXE.log file, showing everything from the last startup down to and including the ORA- error messages.

Comment: Also, the contents of 'initXE.ora'.